# Best jquery modal/overlay?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, overlay

I am searching for jquery modal/overlay for making a login/register overlay. The login/register is enabled for Facebook and Twitter login.

It needs to function such that the size is dynamic. You click "Register/login" and the modal opens. You can either click on "Facebook login" or "Register account". If you click Facebook, a popup opens, authentication is made and the content of the modal is updated to complete registration. If you click "Register account" the modal changes to a form for creating.

So what i need is a jquery modal/overlay which is dynamic and can change size and content without reloading the entire page.

An example of the wanted functionality: http://www.goal.com/

Hope any one can help.

/Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQueryUI Dialog widget is able to resize itself like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 500 );
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height", 500 );
```

See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: But what about changing the content of the dialog/modal?

Comment: If you change the ".selector" element contents then re-open the dialog it will pick up the changes. This widget has an auto-size mode as well: $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height", "auto");